# CSS: Cannot scroll horizontally on elements on the left of the screen

Tags: html, css

So, as i add elements into the body it starts to overflow and show a horizontal scrollbar. Which is desirable, my issue is, that when items overflow to the left side of the window. I cannot scroll to see them, for example

[image]

this has overflown to the left of the screen. But i cannot scroll the window to the left more. You can see that the scrollbar is on it's max left. How can i make it so that it's scrollable to the elements that have overflown to the left of the window.

here is my layout

```
<body>
   // all elements are here
</body>
```

Thanks

Comment: can you provide some reproducable code

Comment: Have you tried `body { direction: rtl; }`?

Comment: @connexo the thing is, the body will overflow in both directions. So i need the overflow to work in both directions

Comment: I am not aware of anything that would solve that. From what I know overflow always only occurs in one horizontal direction, depending on the `direction` of the document/element. The only option I can think of is making sure all the content sits in an element that is large enough to host everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code!

```
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```